# SQLAlchemy Obtain Primary Key With Autoincrement Before Commit

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

When I have created a table with an auto-incrementing primary key, is there a way to obtain what the primary key would be (that is, do something like reserve the primary key) without actually committing?

I would like to place two operations inside a transaction however one of the operations will depend on what primary key was assigned in the previous operation.

Answer (score 95):

You don't need to `commit`, you just need to `flush`.  Here's some sample code.  After the call to [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) you can access the primary key that was assigned.  Note this is with SQLAlchemy v1.3.6 and Python 3.7.4.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    from sqlalchemy.orm import *
    import datetime

    class Blah(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
            self.sessionmaker = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine))
            Base.metadata.bind = self.engine
            Base.metadata.create_all()
            self.now = datetime.datetime.now()

        def test_pkid(self):
            user = User(name="Joe")
            session = self.sessionmaker()
            session.add(user)
            session.flush()
            print('user_id', user.user_id)
            session.commit()
            session.close()

    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use multiple transactions and manage it within scope.