# SQLAlchemy: Object Mappings lost after commit?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I got a simple problem in SQLAlchemy. I have one model in a table, lets call it Model1 here.
I want to add a row in this table, and get the autoincremented key, so I can create another model with it, and use this key. This is not a flawed database design (1:1 relation etc). I simply need this key in another table, because the other table is being transferred to a remote host, and I need the matching keys so the servers will understand each other. There will be no further local reference between these 2 tables, and it's also not possible to create relations because of that.

Consider the following code:

```
object1 = model.Model1(param)
DBSession.add(object1)

# if I do this, the line below fails with an UnboundExecutionError.
# and if I dont do this, object1.id won't be set yet
#transaction.commit()

object2 = model.AnotherModel(object1.id) #id holds the primary, autoincremented key
```

I wished I wouldn't even have to commit "manually".
Basically what I would like to achieve is, "Model1" is constantly growing, with increasing Model.id primary key. AnotherModel is always only a little fraction of Model1, which hasn't been processed yet. Of course I could add a flag in "Model1", a boolean field in the table to mark already processed elements, but I was hoping this would not be necessary.

How can I get my above code working?

Greets,

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Could you please explain what the variable `transaction` is bound to?
- Exactly what statement raises the UnboundExecutionError?
- Please provide the full exception message, including stack trace.
- The 'normal' thing to do in this case, would be to call `DBSession.flush()`. Have you tried that?

Example:

```
object1 = Model1(param)
DBSession.add(object1)
DBSession.flush()
assert object1.id != None # flushing the session populates the id

object2 = AnotherModel(object1.id)
```

For a great explanation to the SA session and what `flush()` does, see [Using the Session](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/session.html#id1).

Basically, `flush()` causes Pending instances to become Persistent - meaning that new objects are INSERTed into the database tables. `flush()` also UPDATEs the tables with values for instances that the session tracks that has changes.

`commit()` always issues `flush()` first.

Within a transaction, you can flush multiple times. Each flush() causes UPDATEs and/or INSERTs in the database. The entire transaction can be commited or rolled back.

Comment: object2 = AnotherModel(object1.id)  <= object1.id isn't bound, because it hasn't been committed to the database yet, and this id wasn't populated yet.

yes, after long nights in the SA docs, I found the flush thing, which indeed helped. I still dont know the difference between flush and commit.
<br /><br />
this thread also describes my original problem more correctly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620610/sqlalchemy-obtain-primary-key-with-autoincrement-before-commit

Comment: thanks that clarifies it a bit more, i still dont see the real difference between commit() and flush(). It's not clearly described. Now in both pages I read on SA, it says C&F both persist an object to the DB. Why the redundancy of 2 commands then? But thanks for the pointer, if I could I'd upvote your answer again:)

Comment: i think your answer is more or less the right one. I still dont get the exact difference between flush and commit. Flush is basically a "subset" of a commit action? I will consider setting your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Flushing and committing are two different things. Flush causes UPDATEs and/or INSERTs in the database. Commit commits the active transaction. I added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get new primary key identifiers to generate without anything being committed, just call session.flush().  That will emit everything pending to the database within the current transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I've only used this with ForeignKeys, so you in the second case rather would do model.AnotherModel(model1=object1), and then it just worked (tm). So I suspect this may be a problem with your models, so maybe you could post them too?

Comment: Yep, but as I said above, my tables arent messed up, this isnt a design problem, basically what I have is a 1:1 relation, which naturally isnt good. but in the end its just a copy of a table, that i will XMLRPC to another server, so actually its not a local 1:1 relation. Out of interest, i will try your way though, my stuff works currently, thanks to flush, but im curious if it had worked your way as well :)